# MultipleObjectsReturned at /vehicle/vehicle_view/ get() returned more than one Vehicle -- it returned 7

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework

`Hello I have more then 1 vehicle in my client side when i was send request from froentend, it return error`

**If I have more than one vehicle, I want all vehicles which save in database of my user_id to be shown to me**

View.py File
@login_required
def vehicle_view(request):

```
vehicle = get_object_or_404(Vehicle, user=request.user)
form = UpdateVehicleForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=vehicle)
context = {'form': form }
if request.method == 'POST':
   
        if form.is_valid():
            vehicle.save()
            messages.success(request, "Vehicle Updated!")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid Data Provided")
return render(request, "user/edit_vehicle.html", context)
```

urls.py
path('vehicle_view/',views.vehicle_view,name='vehicle_view'),

`

Answer (score 0):

get_object_or_404(Vehicle, user=request.user) returns multiple object then it will raise this error depending on scenario you can either use try except in code if you don't want multiple objects to be returned else you can use filter method if you are expecting more than one object.

Example:

```
try:
    vehicle = get_object_or_404(Vehicle, user=request.user)
except Vehicle.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    # Maybe do something.
    raise Http404
```

or use filter :

```
vehicle = Vehicle.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: If I have more than one vehicle, I want all vehicles to be shown to me

Comment: You can use filter in this case i have edited the answer pls check the same.

Comment: I have use filter return this error                                                                    
AttributeError at /vehicle/vehicle_view/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: please debug if multiple object returned or not if yes then i guess in next line after getting multiple objects from db you are passing instance as vehicle which is not single instance.

Comment: I am beginner in django rest framework. How to put try and except in my views.py files please you can explain me where use try and except ?